# Java Spring OAuth2 - Resource server secured by external Auth server

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0

I am beginner in Java Spring and I am trying to understand and setup application for school. (semestral work)
I have simple App what have JPA, DAO, Services and REST API implementation.
I need to secure this API by school OAuth2 server.

All resources on internet showing how to make own app what include Resouce server + Auth Server. To be used by client app. I already have external Auth server.

I am building Backend (REST) only, so I will be testing my app by Postman. I need to access for example `my.app/login` from browser, authorize on OAuth, then recieve JWT, what I can then use in Postman on requests for example to fetch user `my.app/users/3` from my database.

How I can achieve this?

Comment: The semester is about over and finals are starting and you're just getting going? Welcome to SO, questions about specific problems are more likely to get attention.

Comment: I already have everything, but this one little problem with oAuth holding me from continuing

Comment: Spring or Java EE? Best bet is to search for a tutorial and post if you have any specific problems.